# Firefox resolution issue using Capybara's Selenium Driver with Cucumber

Tags: firefox, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I'm not sure when this issue started occurring (maybe a Firefox upgrade), but now when I run my Cucumber tests and use Selenium as my Capybara driver, Firefox opens up with the wrong resolution. Everything looks tiny, which I think means that the resolution is high. When I open Firefox manually, it looks fine.

Is this a setting that can be configured? Is anyone else experiencing this issue? How can I solve this?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7445

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Audry Botalov, the answer is that `selenium-webdriver 2.42.0` introduced a bug. [A commit was made](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=3ec9e0098a00) to adjust the "pixel density setting to be independent from OS settings."  The bug will be fixed in version `2.43.0`

Source: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7445